# c# Ionic.Zip does'nt can't read speacial characters in uppercase

Tags: c#, encoding, character-encoding, zip

I'm triying to read some zip files with the name of file have spanish special characters like ñ, á, é, í, ó, ú and Á, É, Í, Ó, Ú

My code is very simple and works fine for ñ, á, é, í, ó, ú but doesn't work with upper case vocals.

```
using (ZipFile za = ZipFile.Read(@"C:\zip.zip"))
{
    List<ZipEntry> allEntries = za.Entries.ToList();
}
```

If you show in inmediate window the entries values you can see camión2.txt well but CAMIÓN are changed.

```
?za.Entries.ToList()
Count = 2
    [0]: {ZipEntry::CAMIαN.txt}
    [1]: {ZipEntry::camión2.txt}
```

[image: Code Example][image: Zip Content]

Any know how I cant get the filename inside zip with correct characters? I can't change the name of file because are generated by external tool.

Comment: You may need to use `.Read()` with the correct Encoding? https://stackoverflow.com/a/34122488/2524589

Comment: Yes I try with UTF-8 and some other but go to worst because I lost the other special characters